# How does word order work in this sentence?

Tags: word-order

I am very aware of the existence and importance of word order in English to convey accurate messages, but I wonder how did the author know where to locate exactly every word of this sentence...

> *Standard NATO combined arms offensive operational and tactical doctrine.*

...and what is its exact meaning?

Comment: It's not a *sentence* - it's just a (very long and complex) ***noun phrase***. The "head" noun is ***doctrine***. Apparently there's such a thing as an ***arms offensive operational*** doctrine and also a ***tactical*** doctrine. I don't know why the first of those couldn't be called an ***operational arms offensive*** doctrine (perhaps it can; perhaps the particular word order used in your example is arbitrary). Everything before "doctrine" is adjectival (elements like NATO are "noun adjunct" nouns used adjectivally)...

Comment: ...but we probably can't easily match all those elements to categories in the "Royal Order of Adjectives" (– opinion-size-age-shape-color-origin-material-purpose). You'd have to ask a military person rather than an English teacher for the meaning of something like ***combined arms offensive operational and tactical*** doctrine (I've no idea how the elements in that string relate to each other, but *something* is "combined"). But native Anglophones wouldn't normally understand it anyway, and I don't think it should be important for you as a learner to know any more than we do!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, it's certainly a mess. Just FYI, "combined arms" is a phrase meaning different kinds of forces working together, e.g. artillery and infantry. "Operational and tactical" refers to different levels of operations, with "tactical" being more narrow and "operational" being somewhat broader.

Comment: I doubt the original writer even knew or cared whether he started with ***Standard NATO...*** or ***NATO standard*** - but *in principle* it could make a difference which way round those two elements are specified.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a sentence, it's a noun phrase made up of other noun phrases.

A military **doctrine** describes the fundamental principles that govern how a country achieves its military objectives.

An **operational doctrine** provides the high-level framework that can then be used to create a **tactical doctrine** with the specific steps that should be followed to achieve the objectives.

**Combined arms operations** uses different capabilities from different groups simultaneously to make it harder for the enemy to respond and ultimately to win.

So I would say:

**Combined arms offensive operational doctrine** and **Combined arms offensive tactical doctrine** are the two things described, and they are combined as:

> Standard NATO combined arms offensive operational and tactical doctrine.

However, I think **doctrine** should be **doctrines** (plural), since it describes two different doctrines: operational and tactical.

Comment: I think this might just be your personal arbitrary breakdown. For example, can you show any authoritative sources to back up the idea that ***operational*** and ***tactical*** are established clear-cut sub-divisions within military ***doctrines*** (or more specifically, that they're meaningfully identifiable sub-divisions within ***combined arms offensive*** military doctrines)?

Comment: It may be personal but it's not arbitrary. Look up these terms and you will see each of them described as I mentioned above.  However, you can split the words several different ways to suit the answer you're looking for, so this probably  isn't the only answer.

Comment: Meh. Even if it *was* the only credible answer given how each word is used in military terminology, I think the question has no place here unless it's possible to identify how the components are split and joined *without domain-specific knowledge*. We're not here to teach non-Anglophone non-military people about all the different sub-categories within standard NATO doctrine. The question is only meaningful if it's about the actual *syntax* (which I still think is arbitrary).

Comment: So where is your answer FumbleFingers?

Comment: My answer is I'm not a military tactician, and I don't know either the real-world referents OR the particular combinations of words used to reference them by people in the business (which as I already said, are largely arbitrary, and thus not easily understood by non-specialists). I might have helped your cause if you'd provided [***a link to the source.***](https://sputnikglobe.com/20230515/scott-ritter-ukraines-counteroffensive---myth-or-reality-1110370203.html)